# How to know the socket being used in JMS?

Tags: jms, netty, hornetq

I used client and the client will create a connection to server via HornetQ and Netty

Each of 1 minute, server will send heart beat and client (who subscribered) will be received this message. In the message, I included the root IP of server

Everything will be OK if this server had only 1 network card (NIC).

But in the case, server have 2 or more network cards. I met issue.

In the message is received by client, the IP of server not right.

I used `InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress()` to get to root IP and I known it wrong in this case server had 2 NICs

So can you give me some advise, how I can get right IP here?

Some guys said we can refer "the socket being used for getting right IP". Do you know how we can get it?

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). BTW, it's "Thanks in advance", not "Thanks in advanced".

Answer (score 0):

First of all I don't understand why you need IP address, If you think of implementing heartbeat, its not required, If you have used `org.hornetq.jms.client.HornetQJMSConnectionFactory` It automatically does heartbeat check. And If you have two servers and want to differentiate between servers, use a clientId and send it in message header and while listening you can select message based on the clientId or other approach use sync jms calls.